# API URL Special Character being added in Wordpress - the word "region" becomes "®ion"

Tags: url, character

I have an API working using Javascript code hosted on a Wordpress site. The API works fine, then after a number of requests, the requests begin to fail as the URL has replaced

..."region=uk"....

to
..."®ion=uk"...

If tried URL & HTML encoding it and this works, but then breaks in the same manner with the same issue.

Any idea how to permanently/statically set the word "region" in the API URL?

```
<script>

    var API_URL = 'https://api.example.com/US?sport=NFL&region=US&apiKey=____'; 

    var APIXHR = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    function btn() { 
        var url = API_URL;
        APIXHR.open('GET', url, true, 'jsonp');
        APIXHR.send();
        APIXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", procReq, false); 
    } 

    function procReq(e) { 
        if (APIXHR.readyState == 4 && APIXHR.status == 200)     { 
        var resp = JSON.parse(APIXHR.responseText);         
        var Home = resp.data.game.TeamA_TeamB.Teams[0];
        var Away = resp.data.game.TeamA_TeamB.Teams[1];
        document.getElementById("Home").innerHTML = Home;
        document.getElementById("Home").style.textTransform = "uppercase";
        document.getElementById("Away").innerHTML = Away;


</script>
```

Comment: [Clbuttic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). Something's a little over-eager with the escaping there. It's almost impossible to tell you what exactly through without more code/pinpointing the issue.

Comment: I've extracted enough to show functionality, but it is amended so if there is something broke within the code, then it's just a typo after editing:

Answer (score 1):

`&reg` in HTML is the HTML entity for "®". If you're embedding that code in HTML, you need to escape it according to HTML rules. That means you need `...&amp;region=US&amp;apiKey...`. And really every other instance of `&` needs to be escaped too properly speaking.

An alternative is to put the script into an external file and include it with `<script src="...">`; there it's not in an HTML context and you can use plain unescaped Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Deceze, it worked initially then reverted back using the special character. You're correct though, it is embedded in HTML so I'll look to separate the files and give that a try once I work out where to out the external js file